# Is there a way to remove security groups from SharePoint Online groups using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to remove some security groups from several SharePoint site member groups (I am specifically talking about SharePoint groups, not O365 Groups). For example I want to remove the "Everyone except external users" from several sites '...Members' groups.

I know that you can use Add-SPOUser to add a security group to a SharePoint group, but using Remove-SPOUser doesn't seem to work to remove them. I get the following error:
*Remove-SPOUser : The user does not exist or is not unique.*

I have tried using both the security group ID and the display name but neither work:
Remove-SPOUser -Site https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteExample -LoginName "SecGroupDisplayName" -Group "Site Example Members"

Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the PnP PowerShell module can achieve this using the security group display name:

Remove-PnPUser -Identity "SecGroupDisplayName" -Force

Documentation for the command is here:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPUser.html